# How to Save Embedded Images in Powerpoint 2013 To Local Disk Through VBA?

Tags: image, vba, powerpoint

I have lot of pictures embedded in the Microsoft Powerpoint 2013 presentation. In Powerpoint 2013, I can right click on a picture object and then use "Save As Picture" to save the image to local disk. But this is manual way. I want to know if there is any way of automating the same through VBA? I am able to loop through the Shapes collection and then determine the type of the object. But I am not able to figure out which properties or methods are relevant for storing the picture to the local disk? Following is code snippet of iterating through the Shapes collection and determining if the Shape is of type msoPicture

```
  For currentSlideIndex = 1 To totalSlidesCount
    Set currentSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(currentSlideIndex)
    For Each mediaShape In currentSlide.Shapes
        mediaCounter = mediaCounter + 1 'for each shape in the slide
        If currentSlideIndex = 3 Then
              If mediaShape.Type = msoPicture Then
              MsgBox ("Shape Type Picture is " + CStr(mediaShape.Type) )
            End If

        End If
    Next mediaShape
    mediaCounter = 0 'Reset to 0 for the new slide
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the current shape to a picture using the shape's .Export method.

This is normally hidden, so you won't get intellisense help on it by default, so:

Go into the IDE
Press F2 to open the object browser
Rightclick in the pane to the right of Classes, where you see "Members of ..." at the top.
Put a check next to Show Hidden Members

Now you'll get intellisense guidance when you type .Export on a slide shape.

Note also that if a shape is Type 14 (placeholder), it can contain a picture, so you may want to add something like:

```
If mediaShape.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
  If mediaShape.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoPicture Then
    ' it's also a picture
  End If
End if
```

And to add further entertainment value you might also have .Type = msoLinkedPicture, and even in some cases msoEmbeddedOLEObject that happens to be a picture.